# GL_n unique group variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Why is every (reduced, separated, of finite type over an algebraically closed field $\bar{k}$) group variety $G/\bar{k}$ such that $G(\bar{k}) \cong GL_n(\bar{k})$ as groups isomorphic to $GL_n/\bar{k}$?

My idea was to use that the closed points $G(\bar{k}) \subseteq G$ are dense.

Comment: Are you sure this is the statement you are looking for? Not every (one-dimensional) torus over $\mathbb Q$ is split. Consider for instance $x^2+2y^2=1$ over $\mathbb Q$; see page 106 in Poonen's http://www-math.mit.edu/~poonen/papers/Qpoints.pdf . This is a one-dimensional torus over $\mathbb Q$ which is isomorphic to $GL_1$ over $\overline{\mathbb Q}$, but not over $\mathbb Q$. Did you mean to ask whether  $GL_n$ is isomorphic to $G$ over $\bar k$?

Comment: You are right, it should be over $\bar{k}$.